# Laravel: how to get current user in public route

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have same route for authenticated user and guest. If user has logged in, it will show data related to that user.
So, I need to get current user in case he has logged in.

I'd want to ask:
In public route (without using "auth" middleware), how to get current user if he has logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the `Auth::user()` will give you the logged in user. So, to retrieve the logged in user, at first you should check if the user is logged in or not and to do that, you may do something like this:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    $user = Auth::user();
}
```

If you want to use it in a blade template then you may try something like this (to show logged in user's name):

```
@if(Auth::check())
    {{Auth::user()->name}}
@endif
```

[Check more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) (look for `Determining If The Current User Is Authenticated`).